# Replace a column in pandas if another column contains a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I have two columns newlabels and newlabels_tobeReplaced . If newlabels contains the word 'trifurcation' in its sentence, newlabels_tobeReplaced should be replaced to 'trifurcation' 
I have the following code

```
df_new.loc[df_new.newlabels.str.contains('trifurcation'),'newlabels_tobeReplaced'] = 'trifurcation'
```

But , I get this error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[item] = s
```

Any idea, how to get the correct result. 
The problem is that the newlabels has got values like : "Waveforms suggest trifucation disease with mild distal ischemia of left lower extremity at rest at level of ankle."

Comment: Are you sure that that _warning_ (not an error) comes from the line you've given us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get around that warning by reassigning to `df_new` with the copy produced from `assign`

```
df_new = df_new.assign(
    newlabels_tobeReplaced=
    lambda d: d['newlabels_tobeReplaced'].mask(
        d.newlabels.str.contains('trifurcation'), 'trifurcation'
    )
)
```

Comment: It's the same logic just conveniently skipping over the attempt to modify the calling object and reassigning over the top of it instead.

Comment: I'm going more along the lines of an error being something that stops code execution rather than a message that pops up. It's quite possible that my own understanding is off but the warning appears to suggest that the OP does what they are already doing.

Comment: This is the infamous SetWithCopyWarning.  It is complaining that the existing dataframe `df_new` has been flagged as a copy or view of another dataframe.  It got that way as a consequence of how `df_new` was constructed.  It is confusing because the responsible code is prior to what OPs usually post.  The suggested solution is misleading as it is a suggestion as to how the original dataframe ought to have been constructed and not on how to slice or change the current one.  It is often best to produce a copy and carry on.  Unless, you really did intend to keep that link, which is rare.

Comment: Aha, ok, I've misunderstood that the solution you've posted is upstream of the code they posted, sorry. I am well-acquainted with the warning message but with you also referring to is as an "error" I thought I'd gone off-track with my distinction between warnings and errors. When you mentioned "error" again, I thought the warning was actually leading to a code crash here.

Comment: Good call on the language. I've fixed that.